# python DataFrame split dict column to multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The column looks this way:

0     [{'id': 18, 'name': 'Drama'}, {'id': 10769, 'n...

1     [{'id': 18, 'name': 'Drama'}, {'id': 10749, 'n...

2     [{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}, {'id': 27, 'nam...

3                         [{'id': 18, 'name': 'Drama'}]

4                   [{'id': 99, 'name': 'Documentary'}]

5     [{'id': 18, 'name': 'Drama'}, {'id': 28, 'name...

6     [{'id': 10749, 'name': 'Romance'}, {'id': 18, ...

I wish to see ID columns with bool value for each genre:

index id=18   id=10769 id=35  id=27 ...

0     1       1        0      0     ...

1     1       0        0      0     ...

2     0       0        1      1     ...

3     1       0        0      0     ...

...

Comment: Can you add expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Use list comprehension with flattening and then DataFrame contructor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':[[{'id': 18, 'name': 'Drama'}, {'id': 10769}], 
                          [{'id': 99, 'name': 'Documentary'}]]})

print (type(df.loc[0, 'col']))
<class 'list'>

df = pd.DataFrame([y for x in df['col'] for y in x])
print (df)
      id         name
0     18        Drama
1  10769          NaN
2     99  Documentary

#alternative
#df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(x) for x in df['col']], ignore_index=True)
```